# Chart.js {time start / time end} overlap values

Tags: javascript, date, chart.js, chart.js2

I'm trying to use chart.js to graph the amount of work my projects are taking...and the amount of free time I will have.

https://jsfiddle.net/ofydvb40/2

```
{x:"4/6/17",y:"0.33"}, //project 1 start
{x:"6/21/18",y:"0.33"}, // project 1 end
{x:"6/1/18", y:"0.3"}, //project 2 start
{x:"10/30/20",y:"0.33"}, //project 2 end
{x:"1/1/19",y:"0.5"}, //project 3 start
{x:"5/12/20",y:"0.4"}, //project 3 end
```

Above is the time data I am using. You can see on 4/6/17 I am starting a project which I estimate I will finish on 6/21/18 (this will take .33 of my time). You can see I am starting the second project before I start the first. Is there a way in chart.js I can graph this as (from time: end time), and have the y values add up when the times overlap?

If I cant could someone point me toward a helpful resource to preprocess this data accordingly?

Im thinking of using an array to represent it where each index is a date; 0 = starting date, end = end date. Fill up the values for each start - end date -y value and write a function that spits out a date with the corresponding date / y value whenever the y value changes.

Thanks

Comment: Please see [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Code should be posted here (per [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) using the `<>` button in the editor, you can also link external libraries. You should show what you've tried, the errors you get, expected output, etc.